# How to debug error 500 in Swashbuckle 5 for ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I'm getting an error 500 back from Swashbuckle/Swagger, and contrary to the [best related answer I could find](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51670434/4597249), I'm not seeing any additional information in the error response.

[image: Error 500 in Swashbuckle UI]
[image: Swagger Error With No Response Data]

I manually tracked down the problem endpoints by trial-and-error commenting out controllers and actions until I isolated the bad ones, but this is slow and doesn't tell me **why** certain endpoints have a problem. What can I do to get meaningful debug information for the Swagger/Swashbuckle errors?

I'm using Swashbuckle 5.6.0 and Swashbuckle.Core 5.6.0 in an ASP.Net 4.6.2 WebApi app. The only configuration is in a SwaggerConfig.cs file, seen below..

```
public class SwaggerConfig
{
    public static void Register()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
            .EnableSwagger(c =>
                {
                    c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "My.Namespace.Here.WebApi");
                })
            .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
                {
                });
    }
}
```

The `swagger/docs/v1` returns a 500 response with the following:
[image: swagger/docs/v1 error response headers]

Comment: sounds like you need integration tests on your endpoints

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu The endpoints function fine, but are causing errors with Swagger. When Swagger started showing errors, it was deemed of lower priority than continuing development, so now there is a hefty stack of Swagger-specific incompatibility issues. Knowing what Swagger **thinks** is wrong is crucial.

Comment: What do you see if you to the `swagger/docs/v1`

Comment: @HelderSepulveda As shown in the image in the original post, I get a 500 error response with no response body. I added another image showing the request's contents.

Comment: That is very strange can you post a sample of the bad ones you identified

Comment: @HelderSepulveda I'd rather not get into the specific problems here, but it's important to be able to debug the Swagger/Swashbuckle errors so that I can find and fix these and any future errors without guesswork and hide-and-seeking bad endpoints.

Comment: Have you enabled all CLR exceptions on the affected API project, and run with the debugger?

Comment: @Kit I have run it with the debugger and with debug="true" on the system.web > compilation setting. If there's some additional way to enable exceptions/debugging, let me know and I'll try it.

Comment: @nbrosz no one can reproduce your problem with the details given, in my experience when there are errors they will be shown in the body

Comment: @HelderSepulveda I didn't realize that this was atypical behavior. Knowing that is useful, although it obviously doesn't solve the problem. There is interaction with dozens of NuGet packages, including internal proprietary ones, and hundreds of endpoints, models, injected services, etc., all proprietary, so it sounds like this problem just cannot be solved by public help. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe setting [customErrors="Off"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.110)) could help you to get more details?

Comment: @donatasj87 A very good suggestion, but sadly it made no difference.

Comment: The only way I see to maybe troubleshoot this is to add swashbuckle to your solution, so instead of just the binaries in the nuget package, you get the entire code  set some breakpoints and debug swashbuckle a bit

Comment: I ran into the same problem today, latest version of all nuget packages including Swashbuckle 5.6.0, not using Core. I cannot find a way to show any useful information, the error is just 500. Dev tools in chrome show the same - error 500 when opening https://myhost/swagger/docs/v1 (which is the URL used for non core Swashbuckle). Makes it extremely difficult to debug.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `URL` request .change `HTTPS` to `HTTP` .

```
http://localhost:xxxx/...
```

You can NOT simulate HTTPS locally because `SSL certificate` doesn't exist in your local machine.

### Update

i faced status 500 recently when RAM was saturated and there were not enough free memory

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't make a difference. I tried hitting the same URL on `http://...` and I get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, I use **Chrome Dev Tools** to debug this kind of error. Also, you can get more information on **Event Viewer** if you are using Windows OS. Another option is checking the stacktrace from API's Swagger documentation site. For example **api.domain.com/help/index** or **yourApiUrl/swagger/v1/swagger.json**.

I've found a link could be helpful too: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/969

Hope it helps.

Comment: I was using Chrome Dev Tools as well. Our app isn't set up to log to the event viewer, but I'm not seeing logs in our custom app error logger, either. The link's suggestion may be the trick for .Net Core MVC apps, but this is ASP.Net WebAPI and doesn't have middleware in the way that ASP.Net Core does. Now, I **did** try creating a [Delegating Handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers#custom-message-handlers) and the request comes through the pipe, but it evidently doesn't throw an exception. The 500 error response is blank.

Comment: Have you try "yourApiUrl/swagger/v1/swagger.json"? Get any useful information from there?

Comment: That just gives me a 404 Not Found. I've seen mention of a swagger.json but apparently Swashbuckle, at least 5.6 for ASP.Net, uses a different approach. It's just trying to hit `MyApiUrl/swagger/docs/v1`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and couldn't figure out why. My endpoints were all working fine and none of them had Entities from EntityFramework as parameters or sub properties.

But I actually had a public method "public async MyAction(MyEntity entity)" which wasn't used as an API but by an internal bot.

I used the tag `[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]` to ignore it and it went through.

I was using a custom filter to remove un wanted endpoints (the ones that I hadn't flagged with a custom attribute) but since the filtering is done at a later stage by Swagger it didn't reach my filter and I got the out of memory exception before.